# Why isn't my change event firing?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Title pretty much explains it all. I took an example from w3 schools.

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Example: Change event on a select</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function changeEventHandler(event) {
        alert('You like ' + event.target.value + ' ice cream.');
      }
    </script>
   </head>
    <body>
        <label>Choose an ice cream flavor: </label>
        <select size="1" onchange="changeEventHandler(event);">
            <option>chocolate</option>
            <option>strawberry</option>
            <option>vanilla</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

The alert box runs when I run it. However, I can't get my alert box to pop up when I run my code:

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="myCtrl.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myTestApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p>Looping with ng-repeat:</p>
    <label>Job Accounts</label>
    <select id="jobList" size="1" ng-model="selectedJobServer" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option ng-repeat="x in jobServers" value="{{x}}">{{x}}</option>
    </select> 

    <label>Oracle Accounts</label>
    <select ng-disabled={{isDisabled}} ng-model="selectedOracleServer">
      <option ng-repeat="x in oracleServers" value="{{x}}">{{x}}</option>
    </select>

    <p>The selected server is: {{selectedJobServer}}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
 var app = angular.module('myTestApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.isDisabled = true;

    $scope.jobServers = ['server1','server2','server3'];

    function myFunction(){
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
    }
});
```

Is there some interaction with angular that is throwing an issue? Thanks.

Comment: use `ng-change` instead of `onchange` and declare your function as `$scope.myFunction = function() { ... }` I don't think the DOM knows that `myFunction` exists, because it's delcared in an angular controller that is outside of it's scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function should be in `$scope`.

So, you can modify your `myCtrl` code to

```
$scope.myFunction = function(){
   alert("Hello!");
}
```

Also you should modify your event from `change` to `ng-change`.

```
<select id="jobList" size="1" ng-model="selectedJobServer" ng-change="myFunction()">
  <option ng-repeat="x in jobServers" value="{{x}}">{{x}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! It didn't occur to me that mixing plain javascript with angular would be the issue. Once I get a little more rep I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks! Whatever problem, I'm here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular, go all-in with angular. Don't declare generic functions, declare angular functions:

```
$scope.myFunction =  function (){
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
```

And don't use onChange event, use ng-change:

```
 <select id="jobList" size="1" ng-model="selectedJobServer" ng-change="myFunction()">
```